# Best way to divide a list of integers into two list?

Tags: python, list

so I was working on a piece of code today and I was wondering if there was any "easier" way to divide a list into two without knowing the length of the list.
Here's what I've done:

```
#say that myList = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

tran = 0
L1 = []
L2 = []
while (len(myList) > 0):
    tran = myList.pop(0)
    L1.append(tran)
    if (len(myList) > 0):
        tran = myList.pop(0)
        L2.append(tran)
```

I would also like to mention that I'd like each list to take the first value from myList by it's turn. The outcome i'd like to get from this example:

```
L1 = [0,2,4,6]
L2 = [1,3,5]
```

Comment: What's the criterion to divide the list?

Comment: @Christian what do you mean ? I think my last sentence after the code sums it up.

Comment: I mean, what's the desired output? Can you edit your post with it?

Answer (score 8):

You can do something equivalent with slices:

```
>>> mylist = range(7)
>>> mylist
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a,b = mylist[::2],mylist[1::2]
>>> a
[0, 2, 4, 6]
>>> b
[1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> z = [ dd[x].append(y) for x,y in [(('a',i),('b',i))[i % 2] for i in range(1,10)] ]
>>> dd.items()
[('a', [2, 4, 6, 8]), ('b', [1, 3, 5, 7, 9])]
>>>
```